# Image of rational points of a morphism (defined over $\mathbb{Q}$) between affine spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, rational-numbers, affine-geometry, affine-varieties

Let $\phi: \mathbb{A}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^m$ be a polynomial map, where each coordinate is a polynomial defined over $\mathbb{Q}$. Suppose $\phi$ is dominant so the Zarishi closure of $\phi(\mathbb{A}^n)$ is equal to  $\mathbb{A}^m$.

I was wondering are there things we can say about the image of rational points $\phi(\mathbb{A}^n(\mathbb{Q}))$? I assume we can not say that $\phi(\mathbb{A}^n(\mathbb{Q})) = \mathbb{A}^m(\mathbb{Q})$ but can we say something about how these points are distributed in $\mathbb{A}^m(\mathbb{Q})$? Thank you.

Comment: I would say that the images of rational points are rather thinly distributed in the target affine space. 
This is a scandalously vague statement, but consider the morphism $\mathbb A^1\to \mathbb A^1:q\mapsto q^{17}$.  
Don't you agree that a random rational number rarely has a rational 17-th root? [By the way, notice that the above morphism is dominant  because it is dual to the **injective** ring morphism $\mathbb Q[T] \to \mathbb Q[T] $ sending $T$ to $T^{17}$].

Comment: Notice also that despite appearances the **scheme** morphism $\mathbb A^1_\mathbb Q \to \mathbb A^1_\mathbb Q:q\mapsto q^2$ is dominant, even though **no** negative rational number has a rational square root. Again dominance comes from the fact that the corresponding ring morphism $\mathbb Q[T] \to \mathbb Q[T]:T\mapsto T^2$ is injective.

Comment: I agree with your point, thank you.

Comment: You are welcome, dear Takeshi.